# How to keep one view from being rotated by ViewController when orientation changes?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I have a main view, A, which contains another view, B. A also contains a number of buttons and controls.  When the device is rotated, the ViewController for A will rotate A, B and the buttons and controls.  How best can I keep B from being rotated?  I want B to stay put.

View A serves no purpose than to be the container for B and all the other controls.  If I put B directly onto the main window, then I could use A on top of that and retain its ViewController's rotation functionality.  Is this the best way to do this?

To complicate matters, I am using Storyboards and A's ViewController, is the Storyboard scene.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the position and rotation of the view in orientationWillChange.

Comment: You mean to rotate it in the opposite direction, before it gets rotated by the ViewController, so the end-result looks the same?  I can't do that since any rotation of the view will require rerendering of the data in it and that is time-consuming.  What I really want to do is to keep this one view from being changed in any way.

Comment: It wont' never stay there. You have to rotate it in the opposite direction, that's the only solution.
However, rotating the view should't rerender the view. That's how quartz layers work, they cache everthing, even can rasterize views into images. Even if your view is rerendered, it shouldn't be time-consuming. And if it is, you should optimize your rendering instead of workarounds.

Comment: That view is a map.  When I rotate it, the map service tries to fetch the new area that is displayed.  I can't optimize the network traffic that is needlessly created.  I can rewrite the whole mapping service to have it ignore a rotation, but that is what I am trying to prevent.

Comment: You are right, that can be difficult. Try to switch off autoresizing and check if UIViewContentMode is not set to UIViewContentModeRedraw.